# React - Is useState 's setter function able to change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is useState's setter able to change during a component life ?

For instance, let's say we've got a `useCallback` which will update the state.
If the setter is able to change, it must be set as a dependency for the callback since the callback use it.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(false);
const callback = useCallback(
    () => setState(true),
    [setState] // <-- 
);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is, **no, the setter of useState() is not able change,** and the [React docs explicitly guarantee this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) and even provide examples proving that the setter can be omitted.

I would suggest that you do not add anything to the dependencies list of your **useCallback()** unless you know its value can change. Just like you wouldn't add any functions imported from modules or module-level functions, constant expressions defined outside the component, etc. adding those things is just superfluous and makes it harder to read your handlers.

All that being said, this is all very specific to the function that is returned by **useState()** and there is no reason to extend that line of reasoning to every possible custom hook that may return a function. The reason is that the React docs explicitly guarantee the stable behavior of **useState()** and its setters, but it does *not* say that the same must be true for any custom hook.

React hooks are still kind of a new and experimental concept and we need to make sure we encourage each other to make them as readable as possible, and more importantly, to understand what they actually do and why. If we don't it will be seen as evidence that hooks are a "bad idea," which will prohibit adoption and wider understanding of them. That would be bad; in my experience they tend to produce much cleaner alternatives to the class-based components that React is usually associated with, not to mention the fact that they can allow organizational techniques that simply aren't possible with classes.

Comment: Despite this guarantee, the presence of `<StrictMode />` *does* cause instability in the identity of the setter function returned from `useState()`.

Answer (score 32):

The setter **function won't change during component life**.

[From Hooks FAQ:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often)

> (The identity of the setCount function is guaranteed to be stable so it’s safe to omit.)

The setter function (`setState`) returned from `useState` changes on component re-mount, but either way, the `callback` will get a new instance.

**It's a good practice** to add state setter in the dependency array (`[setState]`) when using **custom-hooks**. For example, [`useDispatch` of `react-redux`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#examples) gets new instance on every render, you may get undesired behavior without:

```
// Custom hook
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const CounterComponent = ({ value }) => {
  // Always new instance
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Should be in a callback
  const incrementCounter = useCallback(
    () => dispatch({ type: "increment-counter" }),
    [dispatch]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{value}</span>

      // May render unnecessarily due to the changed reference
      <MyIncrementButton onIncrement={dispatch} />

      // In callback, all fine
      <MyIncrementButton onIncrement={incrementCounter} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis for your answer. Of course when a component is mounted, hooks are reset. My intention was only during one component's life, so I edited the question. Furthermore, my question is only on `useState`setter. Custom hooks, since they are custom, of course we should be ready for them to change anytime unless their docs says otherwise. But because on one hand I didn't see the `setState` hook's documentation say so, but on the other hand experiments show that the setter instance doesn't change during one component's life, so I'm asking the question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: The `built-in` hooks won't change, but it was important for me to note about the custom-hooks.

Comment: Oooh..You say The built-in hooks won't change ? What's the source please ? Maybe you, if you work on the React project .  --- You're right for the custom hooks, anyone might need this info.

Comment: I add a quote from the docs, for other hooks I read it somewhere related to this blog post from Dan Abramov: https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/

Comment: > For example, useDispatch of react-redux gets new instance on every render, you may >get undesired behavior without:
The documentation begs to differ: "The dispatch function reference will be stable as long as the same store instance is being passed to the <Provider>." https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: We talking here about **3rd party** functions, like `useDispatch` of redux not of React's API (although it's stable too in this case, may not be true in other cases).

Comment: Just adding newer links (from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75755882/does-setter-function-change-in-reacts-usestate?noredirect=1#comment133694005_75755882)): The docs pointed above are now marked as legacy; but the stability of setX functions is [still guaranteed in v18.2](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#why-was-the-ref-omitted-from-the-dependency-array)