# React useState - How should I use the setter function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

### **Basic Situation**

Let's say I have a basic `useState` of a number:

```js
const [valueOne, setValueOne] = useState(0);
```

I can write an `increase` function in two ways:

**First way:**

```js
// for one value
const increaseOneFirstWay = useCallback(() => {
  setValueOne((prev) => prev + 1);
}, []); // doesnt have dependency
```

Since the `setter function` of a `useState` doesn't change ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57180908/13172890)), I don't have to add any dependencies to my callback function.

**Second way**

```js
const increaseOneSecondWay = useCallback(() => {
  setValueOne(valueOne + 1);
}, [valueOne]); // has one dependency
```

Here, since I am using `valueOne`, I have to add a dependency, so the callback updates accordingly.

For a basic callback like this, using both ways seems fine. But what if it gets more complicated?

### Complicated Situation

Now, instead of having one state, we will have three:

```js
const [valueTwo, setValueTwo] = useState(0);
const [valueThree, setValueThree] = useState(0);
const [valueFour, setValueFour] = useState(0);
```

This time, the callback will need to use all three values. And some of them together.

**First way:**

```js
// for several values:
  const increaseSeveralFirstWay = useCallback(() => {
    setValueTwo((valueTwoPrev) => {
      setValueThree((valueThreePrev) => {
        setValueFour((valueFourPrev) => {
          return valueFourPrev + valueThreePrev + valueTwoPrev + 1;
        });
        return valueThreePrev + valueTwoPrev + 1;
      });
      return valueTwoPrev + 1;
    });
  }, []); // doesnt have dependency
```

**Second way:**

```js
  const increaseSeveralSecondWay = useCallback(() => {
    setValueTwo(valueTwo + 1);
    setValueThree(valueThree + valueTwo + 1);
    setValueFour(valueFour + valueThree + valueTwo + 1);
  }, [valueTwo, valueThree, valueFour]); // has several dependency
```

Let's say that `valueTwo`, `valueThree`, and `valueFour` also change independently, wouldn't the **first way** be a better choice? Or is there a reason why someone would use the second way (Not opinion-based, but maybe performance? maybe it's not recommended at all to use the first way?)

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-keller-3lned?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 2):

In the case you have multiple states depending on each other the solution is often to use a [reducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). However sometimes the use of a reducer is not necessary since the state can be simplified.

I will here demonstrate the 2 solutions with 2 examples:

**Solution 1: Using a reducer**

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex
> state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
> depends on the previous one. -- [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

```js
import { useReducer } from 'react';

const initialNumberState = {
    valueOne: 0,
    valueTwo: 0,
    valueThree: 0,
};
const numberReducer = (prevState, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'INCREASE_NUMBER') {
        const { valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree } = prevState;
        const newValueOne = valueOne + 1;
        const newValueTwo = valueOne + valueTwo + 1;
        const newValueThree = valueOne + valueTwo + valueThree + 1;

        return {
            valueOne: newValueOne,
            valueTwo: newValueTwo,
            valueThree: newValueThree,
        };
    }
    return prevState;
};

const CustomComponent = (props) => {
    const [numberState, dispatch] = useReducer(
        numberReducer,
        initialNumberState
    );

    const { valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree } = numberState;
    const handleClick = () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE_NUMBER', value: 'not_used_in_this_case' });
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Number 1: {valueOne}</li>
                <li>Number 2: {valueTwo}</li>
                <li>Number 3: {valueThree}</li>
            </ul>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
        </div>
    );
};
export default CustomComponent;
```

**Solution 2: Simplifying the state**

This is the case when we can derive all the data we need from independent states.
For example imagine we are validating a form with separate states:

```js
const [isEmailValid, setIsEmailValid] = useState(false);
const [isPasswordValid, setIsPasswordValid] = useState(false);
const [isFormValid, setIsFormValid] = useState(false);
```

Here setting the state for the email and password validation is easy. However we start encountering issues when we want to set the state for the form.

```js
handlePasswordChange = (event) =>{
    passwordValue = event.currentTarget.value;
    const isValid = validatePassword(passwordValue);
    setIsPasswordValid(isValid);
    const formValid = isPasswordValid && isEmailValid;
    setIsFormValid(formValid); 
    /* Here we will encounter issues since we are updating 
    the form validity on a stale password validity value; */
}
```

Here the solution could have been : `const formValid = isValid && isEmailValid;`

But the optimal solution is simplifying the state:

```js
const [isEmailValid, setIsEmailValid] = useState(false);
const [isPasswordValid, setIsPasswordValid] = useState(false);
const isFormValid = isEmailValid && isPasswordValid;
```

This is a simplistic example and you might think this never happens. But we often over complicate things.