# Do state setters get recreated when the component re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A function defined in some component, gets recreated on every render, if it's not memoized with some `useCallback`, that's what I've learned. Does this apply to state setters, like `setState` in below component?

To my knowledge, `foo` in below component  is typically a function that gets recreated on every re-render.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  const foo = () => console.log("Hello Word");
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState(!state)}>Change state</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `foo` is redefined on every render, yes. Whether `useState` returns a new setter on every call or not is up to React (but it practice it's stable - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57180731/3001761).

Comment: No, `setState` does not get recreated on every render; but I don't see how it would matter in your sample `App` code if it did

Answer (score 4):

No, the dispatch function is guaranteed to always stay the same hence why you don't need to place it in the dependency array. "React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders." [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#basic-hooks)