# Does setter function change in React's useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Defining a state in a React functional component, such as

```js
const [state, setState] = useState();
```

does `setState` (the setter *function*) ever change? I could not find this specified in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), and it is likely not specified and its behavior might change; but does anyone know how it currently works in React? (v16, v18).

While the question may seem irrelevant it may be interesting to know the answer. For example let us say I use some initializer code later in the component, which subscribes to window messages:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const messageListener = () => {
    // Parse the message, and if we decide to, change the state
    ...
    setState(...); // modify component state
  }
  // Subscribe to window messages
  window.addEventListener('message', messageListener, false);

  return () => { // Cleanup, 'destructor' code
    window.removeEventListener('message', messageListener, false);
  }
}, [setState])
```

As this initializer/destructor code needs to mutate the state, it uses `setState`. Then, the `useEffect` hook must depend on the setter `setState`'s *value* (the function). As it is running non-trivial code (create and removing event listeners) that should be executed only once (at least once in my app's lifetime) one would not want to re-run it often, which will happen if React decides to change `setState`.

So, is there a concrete specification on how `useState` creates and passes back the setter function? I imagine it is perfectly possible to have it never mutate (ie. always be the same function object) but it have not find its definition, and might depend on React's version as well.

Comment: From the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) docs: _"React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list."_

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons. The link above points to a legacy website; whilt there is no mention to guaranteeing stability in the [latest 18.2 documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState). Do you know if this condition still holds?

Comment: Yes it does still hold, and those docs were only made legacy 3 days ago (March 17), so when the link was added in the comment it wasn't legacy yet :P.  But it is mentioned in the new docs (just not where you might expect) - See [here](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#why-was-the-ref-omitted-from-the-dependency-array) and the sentence _"The [set](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate) functions returned by useState also have stable identity, so you will often see them omitted from the dependencies too."_